# interact and plotting with ipywidgets events produces many graphs

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, widget, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I am trying to use [widget events](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html) to make an interactive graph.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import ipywidgets as widgets

def myplot(n):
    x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
    y = x**n

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1);
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

    plt.show()
```

Interact works as expected (it changes the figure interactively):

```
widgets.interact(myplot, n=(0,5));
```

However the following snippet creates several figures that appear below as you interact with the slider.

```
n_widget = widgets.IntSlider(
                value=2,
                min=0,
                max=5)

def on_value_change(change):
    myplot(n=n_widget.value)

n_widget.observe(on_value_change)
display(n_widget)
```

Can I update the plot as if I were using widgets.interact()?

---

My current installation is with conda and Python 3.6 (windows machine).

```
ipywidgets                7.1.0                     
jupyter                   1.0.0              
jupyter_client            5.2.1                  
jupyter_console           5.2.0             
jupyter_core              4.4.0              
matplotlib                2.1.1             
notebook                  5.3.1               
numpy                     1.14.0
```

Comment: You have `plt.show()` inside your `myplot` function, so every time that function is called, a new plot window is opened.

Comment: Adding or removing plt.show() doesn't change my problem description: widgets.interact() updates the plot while .observe() doesn't.

Comment: None of them *updates* the plot. But the problem is still related to the use of `plt.show()`. It would be better to `display` the plot instead as shown in the below answer.

Answer (score 5):

*Note that the below is a working solution for ipywidgets version < 7.0. For a solution with ipywidgets >= 7.0 see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1919).*

While in many simple cases `plt.show()` works nicely replacing the output of a cell, this is not always the case. When using interactive elements in Jupyter it is often more helpful to use `IPython.display.display`.

Here you may not want to create a new plot for each interaction. Instead just setting new data to the plot is enough. Then you may autoscale the plot for the new data and display the figure. You may use `IPython.display.clear_output` to clear the output once a new figure would be displayed. This ensures to have always a single plot present in the output cell, independent of the use of `interact` or `observe`.

```
def myplot(n):
    line.set_ydata(x**n)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()
    display(fig)
    clear_output(wait=True)
```

Comlpete notebook:

```
# cell 1
%%capture
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1);
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
y = x**0

line, = ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

def myplot(n):
    line.set_ydata(x**n)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()
    display(fig)
    clear_output(wait=True)

#cell2
widgets.interact(myplot, n=(0,5));

#cell3
n_widget = widgets.IntSlider(
                value=2,
                min=0,
                max=5)

def on_value_change(change):
    myplot(n=n_widget.value)

n_widget.observe(on_value_change)
display(n_widget)
```

[image]

Comment: In my installation, n_widget slider disappears after the first interaction (clears the previous graphs as well the widget). widget.interact() works well.

Comment: Ups, that's bad. I used ipywidgets 6.0 to test this; in that version it's working fine. I'm not sure which one of those is the expected behaviour though. One might argue that `clear_display` should clear everything, including widgets, but that is mostly not desired and in such case one would need an alternative method to clear the output but keeping the widget. I'm unfortunately not aware of any such method.

Comment: Indeed, they changed it in ipywidgets 7.0 ([see first item](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html))

Comment: Too bad. Unfortunately they do not provide any workaround for this. Maybe you have better luck directly inquiring at the ipywidgets GitHub tracker, like you [alredy did here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1919).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do:
`display(fig)`
`plt.close(fig)`
So you do not have to clear_output (that clears everything).